# Decision Tree for Choosing Most Likely Option?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, decision-tree, data-science

I'm trying to find the right ML algorithm. Let's say I have three data columns. I have a binary outcome for each column (either the data column belongs to (Group A) classification or it does not), BUT in each set of three data columns that I feed in, exactly ONE and only one column belongs to Group A.

Which algorithm can I choose to select the ONE BEST result of the three each time? Can I do this with a decision tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision tree aka **ID3**, can be suitable for this simple problem... best way is to check it on the data and see it's output prediction
**ID3** have a problem of over fitting though

basically every classifier can do a good job on this task, if it linearly separable even **SVM** can be a good choice, also I'm suggesting trying basic **neural network** with 1/2 nodes at the output layer for classification of 2 groups

all of them are implemented via various packages and are fairly easy to use (almost any coding language)